# $ f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^k$ on $I$. Then $ a_1=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

$\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^k$ on an open interval $I$ containing $0$. Then $\displaystyle a_1=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$

Sketch of proof :

- For all $x(\neq0)\in I$, $\displaystyle \frac{f(x)}{x}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^{k-1}$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^{k-1}$ also converges at $x=0$ to $a_1$ so it is differentiable and hence is continuous on $I$.

So $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^{k-1}=a_1$

I was wondering if the sketch of proof above is correct.

Comment: It looks fine to me....

Answer (score 1):

L'Hopital's rule actually takes care everything, since $f(x)\longrightarrow 0$ as $x\longrightarrow 0$, so we have $$\lim_{x\longrightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\longrightarrow 0} \frac{f'(x)}{1}=\lim_{x\longrightarrow 0}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}ka_kx^{k-1}=\boxed{a_1}. \quad \blacksquare$$